# Adding ContextLoaderListener to web.xml then my jsp page has a 404 error

Tags: java, spring

when I add

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

to web.xml then `index.jsp` become unable to be found, but DispatcherServlet can work well when I remove ContextLoaderListener:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>    
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/resource/spring/springmvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
```

full structure of my project:

[image]

and jars have been used:

[image]

Even when I remove all the codes in `applicationContext.xml` it didn't work as well, and tomcat didn't show any errors.

these are codes inside the web.xml file:

```
 <display-name>schoolbus</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/resource/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param> 
 <!--  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>  -->  
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>    
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/resource/spring/springmvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>  



  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Can you post your complete web.xml file and your full project structure ? What you have given is small part

Comment: If you only add the `ContextLoaderListener` without a corresponding `context-param` it will try to load the `applicationContext.xml` from the main `WEB-INF` directory. If that fails your application simply doesn't start, leading to 404 errors as there is nothing to be found.

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault. I've already post the complete web.xml file and my full project structure. In the web.xml I've added context-param but it still cannot work.

Comment: Check your logs.